# How do I store and retrieve a binary matrix in a JavaScript TypedArray?

Tags: javascript, matrix, typed-arrays

Suppose I have a binary matrix of size m by n. Each row is n bits long. I would like to store this matrix as space efficiently as possible while still being able to quickly retrieve individual rows. In particular I'd like to be able to do bitwise operations on the rows after retrieving them. To do this I'm using the JavaScript TypedArray.

My attempt at a solution is the following:

0. Initialize the matrix to have a number of columns divisible by 8 (e.g by padding)
1. Flatten the matrix row-wise (i.e put the rows side by side)
2. Convert every 8 bits into an 8-bit integer, returning a flat array of 8-bit integers
3. Initialize buffer and store the array of 8-bit integers as a u8int TypedArray

To retrieve a specific row *i*:

0. Determine the number of 8-bit integers that constitute a single row (since I ensured the number of columns was divisible by 8, this should be a whole number). Call this `rowLength`.
1. Find the offset indices for row *i*, where `rowStartOffset = i*rowLength; rowEndOffset = (i+1)*rowLength-1` and slice the array
2. Convert the integers in the array back into binary format
3. Repeat 0-2 for more rows, then do bitwise operations on them

This works, but I wondered if there was a better way to do this. In particular is there a way to do bitwise operations without having to convert back into binary? (Currently I'm doing this by converting the integers into a binary string and then concatenating). Is there a method which does not use TypedArray?

Comment: this: "_In particular is there a way to do bitwise operations without having to convert back into binary?_" - Answer is Yes: `12 & 24` will covert each operand into a 32 bit int, perform the operation (AND in this case) and return the result as a primitive - which is `8`.

Comment: Is there a way to perform this operation over the entire array (i.e the equivalent of converting each integer for a given row back into its bits, concatenating them to make one bitstring, then doing a bitwise AND?).

Comment: The concatenation bit is an issue with JavaScript as some bitwise operators chop off the MSBs beyond 32 bits. So no, not in the case of binaries > 32bits. But, if you want to do the mathematics on integers, then it simply depends on the operation.